# Selenium Program: Works in Windows, but fails in Linux (No display) server

Tags: selenium

Chromedriver: 2.35
Chrome version: 63

I can successfully run my program in windows, but when I run the same code on Linux server( headless), I get this error:

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: .//div[@id='content']//div[@class='storage_source_1 perk_square_f pointer ib tc imp'] (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.timeoutException(FluentWait.java:264)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:232)
    at born.scrappers.MarketScrapper.marketScrapper(MarketScrapper.java:51)
    at born.scrappers.MarketScrapper.scrapData(MarketScrapper.java:186)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate an element using By.xpath: .//div[@id='content']//div[@class='storage_source_1 perk_square_f pointer ib tc imp']
```

The element is present in the webpage, but still, I get the exception. As I said, the program runs successfully in windows with the same version of chrome driver(for windows), and same version chrome browser.

When I take screenshots, it returns [blank white images](https://serverfault.com/questions/856748/selenium-chromedriver-makes-blank-screenshots). I have tried increasing timeout, still it returns the exception.

Comment: Can you post out your code

Comment: The exception which you have posted is different from what you are saying. so please post here the entire code so that it would make easy for us to check. Also please check combination of versions of browser and selenium which you are using on linux based os and as well its compatibility

Comment: which flavor of the linux you have?

Comment: The error is clear and consise `NoSuchElementException`. Probably you selected the wrong clause of `ExpectedConditions`. Share your code block and the relevant `HTML` and your next steps.

Comment: @Murthi Linux version 4.9.0-3-amd64  (Debian)